# Equivalent replacement for deprecated Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION

Tags: android, android-sensors

I am looking for a solution that replaces the deprecated Android sensor `Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION`.

The most reported solution is to combine `Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER` and `Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD`, then calculate a rotation matrix by using [`SensorManager#getRotationMatrix`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#getRotationMatrix(float[],%20float[],%20float[],%20float[])) and obtain the Euler angles by using [`SensorManager#getOrientation`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#getOrientation(float[],%20float[])).
Another reported solution is to use `Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR`, which also ends up with a rotation matrix and the Euler angles by using `SensorManager#getOrientation`

Unfortunately those behave totally different to `TYPE_ORIENTATION` when rotating the mobile device. Try both types while your phone is laying on the desk and then turning it up (pitch) to 90° (the screen is now directly facing to you). The calculated Euler angles of azimuth and roll get really wild (cause of something called the [Gimbal lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock) problem) while the degree values retrieved with `TYPE_ORIENTATION` are pretty stable (not accurate but quite ok). Every value (yaw, pitch and roll) of `TYPE_ORIENTATION` seems to be some kind of "projected" degree without having the Gimbal Lock problem.

What would be a way to get similar degrees (for yaw, roll and pitch) without using the depreciated `TYPE_ORIENTATION` sensor (maybe from the rotation matrix)? How does the `TYPE_ORIENTATION` algorithm does it internally?

Answer (score 0):

The `azimuth` in `getOrientation` is the angle between the magnetic north and the projection of the device y-axis into the world x-y plane. When the device is up to 90° the projection is a zero vector, thus the azimuth does not make sense in this case and can be any value. Physically, trying to find the angle between the magnetic north and a vector pointing to the Sky will not make sense.
You should look at my project at https://github.com/hoananguyen/dsensor/blob/master/dsensor/src/main/java/com/hoan/dsensor_master/DProcessedSensor.java

Comment: How does that detect correct orientation and rotation landscape/portrait?